# COUNT(*) does not count correctly

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a mysql query.

```
SELECT switch_id, port_id, isp_service.service, isp_service.id
FROM traffic, isp_service
WHERE datetime>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' 
AND datetime<'2013-09-02 00:00:00'
AND isp_service.id=traffic.isp_service_id
GROUP BY switch_id, port_id
```

This query returns me 1000 rows.
Now I am trying to count how many users each service has so I did:

```
SELECT ris.id, COUNT(*) as numberOfUsers
FROM 
 (SELECT switch_id, port_id, isp_service.service, isp_service.id
 FROM traffic, isp_service
 WHERE datetime>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' 
 AND datetime<'2013-09-02 00:00:00'
 AND isp_service.id=traffic.isp_service_id
 GROUP BY switch_id, port_id)ris
GROUP BY ris.id
ORDER BY ris.id
```

Now, how is possible that if I sum up the column numberOfUser the results is bigger than 1000?

Comment: 1,000 rows is quite exact.  Perhaps the interface you are using for writing queries limits the number of rows to 1000 in the first case.

Comment: Your usage of `group by` in the first query is invalid (every other DBMS would reject it). Additionally I don't see why you would need a `group by` at all in the first query as you are not applying any aggregates anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that count works perfect, if you need help with the query please add the structure and some data in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please explain me a bit better? In the first query I use GROUP BY because I can't use DISTINCT on more than 1 column. Am I wrong?

Comment: Of course you can use `distinct` on more than one column. You may want to read this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ to understand what's wrong with your `group by` usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about proper `join` syntax and to prefix all columns with table aliases.  A better way to write the second query is:

```
SELECT ris.id, COUNT(*) as numberOfUsers
FROM (SELECT switch_id, port_id, s.service, s.id
      FROM traffic t join
           isp_service s
           on s.id = t.isp_service_id
      WHERE datetime >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND datetime < '2013-09-02 00:00:00'
      GROUP BY switch_id, port_id
     ) ris
GROUP BY ris.id
ORDER BY ris.id;
```

This query has a problem, because `s.service` and `s.id` are included in the `select`, but they are not in the `group by`.  That means that MySQL takes arbitrary values for them.

It is unclear what specifies a "user".  If the `switch_id`/`port_id` pair identifies a user, then the query should produce correct results.  However, you are likely to be missing `id` values that have users.  You might be able to do this in one query:

```
SELECT s.id, count(*) as NumberOfUsers, count(distinct switch_id, port_id) as NumberOfUsers2
FROM traffic t join
     isp_service s
     on s.id = t.isp_service_id
WHERE datetime >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND datetime < '2013-09-02 00:00:00'
GROUP BY s.id;
```

I am not sure which count is most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this.